# WooCommerce default email functionality stop and mail using custom plugin

Tags: plugins, woocommerce

My question is I want to stop "WooCommerce default mailing on New Order placement" with the help of my custom plugin. I dont want to do this task manual, i want everything will work using my custom plugin. And final mail will send using my custom plugin.
Can anyone let me know how should i do this? How can i change functionality of a plugin using another plugin?
Thanks.